# controll more then 3 divs with *ngIf in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Is it possible to controll 3 divs using *ngIf in Angular 2?

Can I do something like

```
<div *ngIf="planState=plan1">show plan 1</div>

<div *ngIf="planState=plan2">show plan 2</div>

<div *ngIf="planState=plan3">show plan 3</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes (assuming those are double equal to represent an if case) but you might want to checkout `ngSwitch` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update your plunker code as below and it works:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="OnButtonClick(1)">select - 1</button>
  <button (click)="OnButtonClick(2)">select - 2</button>
  <button (click)="OnButtonClick(3)">select - 3</button>
  <h5>You selected : {{value}}</h5>

  <hr>
  <div>
     <div *ngIf="value==1">1. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngIf="value==2">2. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngIf="value==3">3. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngIf="value==0">Default Template</div>

  </div>
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {
  value:number=0;

  OnButtonClick(value)
  {
    this.value=value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just miss comparison operator it should be `==` instead `=` only.

You can also use **[hidden]**. advisable to use ngIf prior to [hidden]

```
<div *ngIf="planState==plan1">show plan 1</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div [hidden]="planState!=plan1">show plan 1</div>
```

Comment: If you are using `[hidden]`, the comparison should be inverted! ;)

Comment: *ngIf was not working for me. I used ngSwitch Plunker Link [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXmUm2Th5QGIRmTFBtQG?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***ngIf** in angular 2 which is equivalent to ng-if of angular